# If else in Mysql Update query

Tags: mysql

I need a query to update some fields in a table based on count of another field.

```
Update 
    bank_sample_map 
LEFT JOIN 
    sample_details ON bank_sample_map.sample_track_id = sample_details.sampletrack_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    order_details ON order_details.sample_detail_id = sample_details.sample_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    test_details ON test_details.test_detail_id = order_details.test_detail_id
SET 
    bank_sample_map.sample_id = sample_details.sample_id, bank_sample_map.order_id = order_details.order_number,
bank_sample_map.testid = test_details.test_id,bank_sample_map.test_cost = test_details.test_cost

WHERE 
    bank_sample_map.sample_id IS NULL 
    AND bank_sample_map.order_id IS NULL 
    AND bank_sample_map.testid IS NULL 
    AND (select count(order_number) < 2  from order_details where sample_detail_id = sample_details.sample_id);
```

If(count(order_number) < 2) I need to update sample_id,order_id,testid,test_cost
Else update sample_id only.

How to change my query to satisfy this condition.

Comment: An outer join in an update seems like a slightly counterintuitive idea - but that doesn't mean it's wrong, I guess.